# How do I call a function stored in a jQuery array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hook

I have an array of hooks in jQuery that are executed before I load data into a grid. In one case, however, I want to remove the hook, then add it back for later. Whatever I'm doing is not working just right... it's probably a syntax error because I'm still somewhat new to jQuery. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Current code:

```
var preLoad = this.opts.hooks.preLoad.pop();
//stuff happens
//now I want to add the preLoad hook back
this.opts.hooks.preLoad.push(function(report) { preLoad(report); });
```

**EDIT**
It turns out the issue lies elsewhere in the code. However, I'd still like to know how best to accomplish this.

Comment: Is this in any way related to jQuery?

Comment: Well I guess it's more just javascript syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not just add the function you removed like this?

```
var preLoad = this.opts.hooks.preLoad.pop();
//stuff happens
//now I want to add the preLoad hook back
this.opts.hooks.preLoad.push(preLoad);
```

And are you sure it's always the last one in the array that you want to remove?

Comment: Yes it is, the problem lies elsewhere in the code unfortunately. I had been doing this and it wasn't working which led me to believe I had to wrap preLoad in the function() but I think the way the code is written is adding the hook to the wrong object. My mistake!

Answer (score 4):

You access it the same way as any other variable stored in any other array.

```
 this.opts.hooks.preLoad[0](myReport)
```

Answer (score 2):

It probably has to do with the fact that you are "canning" the argument "report" when you push the function back on the stack.

Try doing it like that:

```
var preLoad = this.opts.hooks.preLoad.pop();
//stuff happens
//now I want to add the preLoad hook back
this.opts.hooks.preLoad.push(preLoad);
```

I've tested it here http://jsfiddle.net/fWRez/

Answer (score 1):

The example you gave has nothing to do with jQuery and is pure Javascript. Also, beware that what you are doing in your example is... not right. Consider this :

```
var ReportManager {
   ...
   replace: function(report) {
      var preLoad = this.opts.hooks.preLoad.pop();
      //stuff happens
      //now I want to add the preLoad hook back
      this.opts.hooks.preLoad.push(function(report) { preLoad(report); });
   }
}
```

If you execute this :

```
replace(null);
replace({foo:'bar'});
replace(null);
```

Your `this.opts.hooks.preLoad` array will look like this :

```
Array(
   0: function(report) { return function(report) { return function(report) { ... } } }
)
```

Because you are pushing the function wrapped into itself every time you execute your code. I'm not sure why you need to `pop` and `push` it back in again, but this just look odd.

Also, Javascript is a *very* flexible language; which mean that you can do many weird stuff, like

```
"hello".concat(" world");            // -> 'hello world'
0.toString();                        // -> '0'
(function(a) { return a; })("foo");  // -> 'foo'
(function() { return false; })() || (function() { return true; })(); // -> true (executes both functions)
(function(i) { return [i*2,i*3,i*4]; })(2)[1]; // -> 6
$('selector')[0];                    // ...
// etc.
```